# How to associate unrelated objects created through abstract factory

Tags: c++, design-patterns

currently I am working on one design which is in initial stage and below is the some homework I have done so far, but it doesn't seems to be ok and I have been facing some issue with this. it is clear from below code that device factory has been used for device object and library object  creation purpose. 
now the job is after getting device object from factory, connect function will be called which will make sure that connection successfully done and now any relevant parser (XML,JSON or other supported one)needs to be used for device to fetch the data . Now here both task (selection of device and library)  has been done separately so now job is I need to impose selected library on selected object and for the same assignment operator has been overloaded in Device class but I am getting error "cannot convert 'Library*' to 'Device*' in assignment" while assigning library object to device object . apart from this I also need to use Library class as a abstract class which is not possible in current implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class Library
{
public:
    virtual void lib_func();
    virtual ~Library(){}
};

class JSON : public Library
{
public:
    void lib_func()
    {
        cout<<"connect through USB"<<endl;
    }
};

class JXML : public Library
{
public:
    void lib_func()
    {
        cout<<"Connect through TCP"<<endl;
    }
};

class XML : public Library
{
public:
    void lib_func()
    {
        cout<<" connect through BT"<<endl;
    }
};

class Device
{
public:
    virtual void connect()=0;
    const Device& operator =(const Device& obj);
    virtual ~Device(){}
private:
    Library * obj;
};

const Device& Device:: operator =(const Device& rhs)
{
    Library *objorig=obj;
    obj=new Library(*rhs.obj);
    delete objorig;
    return *this;
}

class D1: public Device
{
public:
    void connect()
    {
        cout<<" connect through USB"<<endl;
    }
};

class D2 : public Device
{
public:
    void connect()
    {
        cout<<"Connect through TCP"<<endl;
    }
};

class D3 : public Device
{
public:
    void    connect()
    {
        cout<<" connect through BT"<<endl;
    }
};

class Devicefactory
{
public:
    virtual Device* create_instance(const char* type)=0;
    virtual Library* populate_library(const char* type)=0;
};

class factory : public Devicefactory
{
public:
    Device* create_instance(const char* type)
    {
        if(!strcmp(type,"D1"))
        {
            return new D1();
        }
        else if(!strcmp(type,"D2"))
        {
            return new D2();
        }

        else if(!strcmp(type,"D3"))
        {
            return new D3();
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    Library* populate_library(const char* type)
    {
        if(!strcmp(type,"XML"))
        {
            return new XML();
        }
        else if(!strcmp(type,"JSON"))
        {
            return new JSON();
        }
        else if(!strcmp(type,"JXML"))
        {
            return new JXML();
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Devicefactory *obj=new factory;
    Device * object = obj->create_instance("D3");
    Library *object1 = obj->populate_library("JSON");
    object->connect();
    object=object1;
    object->lib_func();
    delete object;
    delete obj;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning factory-made objects anywhere. You are trying to assign pointers. It is not clear why you think you should be able to do either. Your only `opetator=` is not able to take a Library.

Comment: The job of factory is only return the objects based on passed information . now suppose if it return device object d1 and it is supposed to work on json library then it will use json parser to fetch the require details. currently design is not yet completed and I am looking for more improvement in this.

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: question is same (association between diiferent objects created through same interface), How to associate device object with library object so that device object can be imposed on library object in order to avail library functionality, because device object needs this library  to fetch the details. some device object will require json library or some will require xml based on device support.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but it seems to me you simply need to add a `setLibrary` member function to `Device`:

```
void setLibrary(Library* library) { 
    obj = library; 
}
```

Then in you main function use it like so:

```
Device* object = obj->create_instance("D3");
Library* object1 = obj->populate_library("JSON");
object.setLibrary(object1);
```

I'm assuming the device should not own the library and you simply want to associate the library with the device.

There is no need to write an assignment operator.

You probably meant to make `lib_func` abstract in `Library`:

```
virtual void lib_func() = 0;
```

Off-topic: I would recommend returning a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer from your factory so that you don't have to remember to call `delete` (you forgot to delete the `Library`). There is no reason to allocate the factory using `new` you could just create it on the stack.

Comment: This approach looks good as Library can be still used as a abstract class, but still you can't assign the device object to library object and if you do this compiler will flash the same  error message which I discussed in my thread due to object assignment.

Comment: @user2997518 Why do you want to assign the device object to the Library? Surely the library doesn't need to know anything about the device? I thought you wanted to "assign" the library to the device, which is what you can do with the `setLibrary` member function.

Comment: setLibrary and assignment operator both does the same job in this context. I had already mentioned that based on device support library can be configured. one device object can support multiple library . so design should be versatile.

Comment: @user2997518, You _could_ use an overloaded assignment operator instead of a `setLibrary` member function if you really wanted to. Either way, as long as it accepts a `Library*` it can support multiple libraries that implement the `Library` interface. So my design offers the versatility you were looking for.

Comment: I already did the same and then you suggested to use setLibrary member function. Please suggest concrete details if you do have any, may be if possible you can also share code snippet just like shared by user user2907032 by giving proper reason. FYI...populate_library already take Library* as a parameter to support the mulitple libraries and whenever new libraries comes over there then device needs to support as well. so it is taking care there properly now design should maintain proper abstraction level so that code shouldn't reveal the way device is imposing the supported type.

Answer (score 0):

use private inheritance to implement the same , so that you can override  the virtual function lib_info in Device class and implement the same . apart from  in this approach your Library class will be abstract .Below is the approach which you need to use to avoid any assignment error. Usually private inheritance is used to override the virtual function which is not possible with composition. 
**step 1**:override the lib_func in your Device class.

```
class Device : private Library
{

public:

virtual void connect()=0;
void lib_func();
virtual ~Device(){}


};
```

**step 2:**
below is the implementation of overridden function

void Device :: lib_func()
    {

Devicefactory *obj=new factory;

```
 Library *object1=obj->populate_library("JSON");
 object1->lib_func();

 }
```

**step 3:**
Now you need to use only Device object only in driver function, This is class
abstraction.

```
int main()
  {

  Devicefactory *obj=new factory;

   Device * object=obj->create_instance("D3");

    object->connect();

     object->lib_func();

    delete object;

    delete obj;

    return 1;

    }
```

Comment: This looks good solution. This abstraction will also help me to hide details about library configuration and apart from this now library configuration can be monitored inside overridden function. I was looking similar kind of solution. Private inheritance can be justified here as there is no direct relationship between device and library and device needs to be implemented in terms of Library object.

Comment: I also would like you  to use smart pointer . i believe sure it was permitted in your application.below is small code snippet for you  Please have a look

Comment: unique_ptr<Devicefactory>obj<new factory>  . Apart from this i believe you might have mapping for device and supported library in configuration file to pass the information to your populate_library factory.

Comment: one more thing which i would like to suggest   you that , if you are implementing assignment operator in your abstract class then it should be either protected  (derived class copying purpose) or unimplemented if not required, by assigning delete keyword to your assignment operator or declare it in private if you don't have latest c++ compiler (c++11)

Comment: i do agree with you as we don't know the size of actual object which is going to be copied and apart from this object slicing will also come in to the picture, so ideally it  should be dropped completely. below is the good link for the same :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910254/can-i-call-abstract-base-classs-public-assignment-operator-from-another-class-e. configuration file will be used for mapping between device and supported library type purpose and i am going to replace  lib_func(); with lib_func(fstream &configfile) . Now this topic  is closed from my end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the approach which is implemented  through without assignment operator and private inheritance.

#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<memory>
#define RESULT_ERROR 0
#define RESULT_SUCCESS 1 
using namespace std;

   class Library
   {

    public:

    virtual void lib_func(fstream &obj)=0;

    virtual ~Library(){}

    };

     class JSON : public Library

    {

    public:

    void lib_func(fstream &obj)

    {

    cout<<"using json to fetch the object"<<endl;

    }

    }; 

    class JXML : public Library

    {

    public:

    void lib_func(fstream &obj)

    {

    cout<<"using JXML to fetch the object"<<endl;

    }

    };

    class XML : public Library

    {

    public:

    void lib_func(fstream &obj)

    {

    cout<<"use XML to fetch the data"<<endl;

    }



    }; 


    class Device 
    {

    public:
    Device( Library *lib=NULL) : lib(lib){}
    virtual void connect()=0;

    int16_t  impose_library(fstream &obj);
    virtual ~ Device(){}
    protected:
    Library *lib;

    };

 class D1: public Device
   {

    public:
     D1():Device(lib)
      {

      }
    void connect()

    {

    cout<<" connect through USB"<<endl;

    }

    }; 

    class D2 : public Device

    {

    public:
 D2():Device(lib)
      {

      }
    void connect()

    {

    cout<<"Connect through TCP"<<endl;

    }



    };

    class D3 : public Device

    {

    public:
    D3():Device(lib)
      {

      }
    void  connect()

    {

    cout<<" connect through BT"<<endl;

    }



    }; 



class Devicefactory 

{

public:

virtual Device* create_instance(const char* type)=0;

virtual Library* populate_library(const char* type)=0;

};

class factory : public Devicefactory 

{

public:

Device* create_instance(const char* type)

{

      if(!strcmp(type,"D1"))

       {

           return new D1();

       }  

       else if(!strcmp(type,"D2"))

       {

           return new D2();

       } 



       else if(!strcmp(type,"D3"))

       {

           return new D3();

       } 

       return NULL; 

    }



  Library* populate_library(const char* type)

  {

      if(!strcmp(type,"XML"))

       {

           return new XML();

       }  

       else if(!strcmp(type,"JSON"))

       {

           return new JSON();

       } 



       else if(!strcmp(type,"JXML"))

       {

           return new JXML();

       } 

       return NULL; 

    }



};

     int16_t Device :: impose_library(fstream &fconfig)
    {

   std::unique_ptr <Devicefactory> obj (new factory);
   std::unique_ptr<Library> object1 (obj->populate_library("JSON"));
    if(object1!=NULL)
     {
     object1->lib_func(fconfig);
     return RESULT_SUCCESS;
     }

     else
     {
       return RESULT_ERROR;

     }

}
    int main()

    { 

  int16_t  result;
  fstream  fconfig  ;

   std::unique_ptr<Devicefactory> obj (new factory);

 std::unique_ptr<Device> object(obj->create_instance("D3"));

     object->connect();

     result=object->impose_library(fconfig);
     if(result==RESULT_ERROR)
     {
       cout<<"NULL object"<<endl;
     }

    return 1;

    }
```